# Printing JSON (from a php) through ajax to a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

Now this one seems a little complicated and maybe I have got myself into more than I can manage but it seems the only way I can achieve what I need.

I am a complete novice and am going at this blindly for a project I'm working on (this is the most complicated thing in the whole project) so any help would be much appreciated!

I basically have a bootstrap webpage, this webpage displays a users list (from php in a while loop). What I need the user to be able to do is select a user from this and edit the details in a form in a bootstrap modal.

So far I have everything working, modal loading etc and from various sources online have wrangled JSon but I've never learnt it and am way out of my depths. Currently it is printing '[object HTMLCollection]' in each field.

Firstly here is the HTML for the modal & list:

Modal (This comes up perfectly)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel"></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="username" class="form-control" id="username"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <input type="button" class="form-control" value="Change Password" onClick="changeRandomPassword();">&nbsp;
                                </span>
                                <input type="text"  name="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="" required></input>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
             </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName" class="control-label">Surname:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName"  class="form-control" id="lastName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="jobTitle" class="control-label">Job Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="jobTitle"  class="form-control" id="jobTitle">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="TaskTeam" class="control-label">Task Team:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="TaskTeam"  class="form-control" id="TaskTeam">
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit Changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the php list: (again no trouble here)

```
<?php 
include("dbconnect.php"); 

$dbQuery= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastName ASC;"); 

while($dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($dbQuery))
{
$userID = $dbRow['id'];
$username = $dbRow['username'];
$firstName = $dbRow['firstName'];
$lastName = $dbRow['lastName'];
$jobTitle = $dbRow['jobTitle'];
$userteam = $dbRow['TaskTeam'];
$admin = $dbRow['admin'];

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal" value='.$userID.' id="user" name="user"" data-user='.$userID.'><span title="Edit" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'.$firstName.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$lastName.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$jobTitle.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$userteam.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$admin.'</td>';

echo '<td>';
echo '<a href="deleteUser.php?id='.$userID.'">';
echo '<button type="button" name="delete_row" id="delete_row" class="close">';
echo '<span title="Delete" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">';
echo '</span>';
echo '<span class="sr-only">';
echo 'Delete';
echo '</span>';
echo '</button>';
echo '</a>';
echo '</td>';

echo '</tr>';
}

echo mysql_error();
mysql_close();

?>
```

Here is where the problem must lay:

```
<script>
    $('#editUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) 
    {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var recipient = button.data('user')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit ' + recipient + "'s details.")
        $(function () 
          {
            $.ajax(
            {  
                type: 'GET',
                url: "getUser.php?id=",             
                data: 'recipient',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(obj, function(key, val) 
                    {
                        console.log(val);           
                         var id = data[0];              
                         var firstName = data[1];       
                         var lastName = data[2];
                         var username = data[3];
                         var password = data[4];
                         var jobTitle = data[5];
                         var TaskTeam = data[6];
                         var admin = data[12];      
                    });
                }
            })
        })
        modal.find('.modal-body #firstName').val(firstName)
        modal.find('.modal-body #lastName').val(lastName)
        modal.find('.modal-body #username').val(username)
        modal.find('.modal-body #password').val(password)
        modal.find('.modal-body #jobTitle').val(jobTitle)
        modal.find('.modal-body #TaskTeam').val(TaskTeam)
    })
</script>
```

Lastly here is php file to get the user details: (This works too but only is done manually- This is the bulk of it excluding passwords etc)

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$userid = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

/*
$user = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $details = array(
    "username"          => $row['username'],
    "firstName"         => $row['firstName'],
    "lastName"          => $row['lastName'],
    "taskTeam"          => $row['taskTeam']
  );
  $user[] = $details;
}
echo json_encode($user);
$conn->close();
*/

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $array = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($array, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Sorry for lack of Mysqli I know this is the latest standard and am currently implementing it in this project.

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Try checking the network tab in your developer tools to see the response body and post that as well

Comment: @ste-fu currently working off Notepad ++ and checking the changes via FTP and checking within the browser for changes. Not sure how to get a response body...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is here:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(obj, function(key, val) 
{
    console.log(val);           
     var id = data[0];              
     var firstName = data[1];       
     var lastName = data[2];
     var username = data[3];
     var password = data[4];
     var jobTitle = data[5];
     var TaskTeam = data[6];
     var admin = data[12];      
});
```

You've already told your AJAX call that you are expecting JSON back from your PHP script. You did this with `dataType: "json"`. So there is no reason to do this here: `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`. Since you told your AJAX call you are going to receive JSON back, it automatically parses it for you when the PHP script completes.

To access the data simply use the `.` syntax. For example, `data.firstName`

Also, you may need to need to change this line in your PHP file from

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

**to**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Also, your PHP script needed some cleaning up:

```
<?php 
include("dbconnect.php"); 

$dbQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastName ASC;"); 

while ($dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($dbQuery)) {

    $userID    = $dbRow['id'];
    $username  = $dbRow['username'];
    $firstName = $dbRow['firstName'];
    $lastName  = $dbRow['lastName'];
    $jobTitle  = $dbRow['jobTitle'];
    $userteam  = $dbRow['TaskTeam'];
    $admin     = $dbRow['admin'];

    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal" value='.$userID.' id="user" name="user"" data-user='.$userID.'><span title="Edit" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        </td>
        <td>'.$firstName.'</td>
        <td>'.$lastName.'</td>
        <td>'.$jobTitle.'</td>
        <td>'.$userteam.'</td>
        <td>'.$admin.'</td>
        <td>
            <a href="deleteUser.php?id='.$userID.'">
                <button type="button" name="delete_row" id="delete_row" class="close">
                    <span title="Delete" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Delete</span>
                </button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>';
}

echo mysql_error();
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: YES! OMG IT WORKED! You have no idea how grateful I am. Been stuck on this for nearly over a month and got no help from my professors! How can I repay you! I don't even have rep15 to upvote the answer, only on 13. damnit! Are you on twitter etc? haha thanks again

Comment: Awesome, I am glad it worked for you man. Nope, no twitter account, just stackoverflow. Let me know if I can help with anything else. God bless!

Comment: no seriously thank you, any idea how to work with a checkbox here? So that if a value is is returned it checks a checkbox in the modal? I don't want too much

Comment: Yep, just do this `$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true)`. Be sure to change '#myCheckbox' to the ID of your checkbox.